# Mysql where clause bug?

Tags: php, mysql

I programmed the following in php and mysql:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];  
if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT disco, fecha, amazon from discos where id=? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);    /* NOTE: "s" doesn't work */
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($disco, $fecha, $amazon);        
    if($stmt->fetch()){
        /* Do some stuff */
    }
}
```

The thing is, when the value of $id is, for example: 100abcd, the query still fetches, whereas it shouldn't, as there is no id called like that, BUT it fetches the id 100.

Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: `->bind_param("i", …)` casts it to an integer. If you want to leave type coercion to MySQL, then bind it as string.

Comment: Yea, I already had it with "s" instead of "i", and still doesn't work.

Comment: two things check that `$id` have any value or not also put some `ORDERBY` clause before `LIMIT` and check. please try

Comment: $id has the value of 100abcd when I debug it, what do you want me to do with ORDERBY?

Comment: id is non-numeric, and check manually in your table that this id exist or not actually? because id normally we use as integer not non-numeric. thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's an implicit conversion from string to int -- it's the equivalent of id = CAST('100abcd' AS unsigned);

```
> SELECT CAST('100abcd' AS UNSIGNED);
+-----------------------------+
| CAST('100abcd' AS UNSIGNED) |
+-----------------------------+
|                         100 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Yea, I already tested it with "s" instead of "i", and still doesn't work.

Comment: What is "doesn't" work? If you're trying to validate the input, do it in the application logic ```if (!is_numeric($id)) { echo 'invalid id'; exit; }```